# Complexity of Quadratic Programming where the symmetric matrix Q is positive semidefinite only in the feasible directions

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

playing around with stuff for my dissertation, I derived a quadratic problem in the general form
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\min_{x} \quad & x^TQx + c^Tx \\
\textrm{s.t.} \quad & Ax \leq a\\
  & Bx = b \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

I know that the objective function is convex on the feasible set. But this does not imply positive semi-definiteness of Q in all directions of $\mathbb{R}^n$. We only know that Q is positive semi-definite in all feasible directions (when fixing any feasible point).

My question is whether we still have polynomial time solvability of this problem based on the objective function being convex on the feasible set or whether negative curvature in non-feasible directions could destroy polynomial time solvability.

Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming#Complexity wants Q to be positive semi-definite overall. I also looked into the referenced papers which only talk about Q, independent of how it interacts with the feasible set.

Any help (with references please) is very appreciated!

Comment: obviously only convexity on the kernel of $B$ matters. You can explicitly replace $x$ with $y+x^*$, with $x^*$ a solution to $Bx=b$ and $y\in Ker B$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint, it brought me to the term "constraint elimination" which showed that the convex problem as described in my case can be transformed to a quadratic problem in lower dimensions where the matrix Q is positive semidefinite!